# Calculating exponential moving averages via recursive cte mysql

Tags: mysql

New to SQL here. I'm planning to calculate the 3 day exponential moving average of a time series data.
Here's a sample table:

| date | symbol | close |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-01 | abc | 10 |
| 2022-09-01 | def | 50 |
| 2022-09-02 | abc | 12 |
| 2022-09-02 | def | 55 |
| 2022-09-03 | abc | 14 |
| 2022-09-03 | def | 60 |
| 2022-09-04 | abc | 16 |
| 2022-09-04 | def | 65 |

*(Someone pointed out before in my previous question to construct a fiddle on my sample data. I'd like to apologize as I'm having trouble making one right now. I'm new to these platforms)*

So my rules for calculating the ema are:

1. when the data is less than 3 days, ema should be null
2. at the 3rd day, ema should be the arithmetic mean
3. for the 4th day and succeeding, formula is (close * alpha) + prev. ema * (1-alpha)

Here's my code so far:

```
use db1;
set @prd = 3;
set @alpha = 2/(@prd + 1);
with recursive cte1
as (select dt,
        symbol,
        close,
        row_number() over (partition by symbol order by dt) as id
from tbl1),
ema as (
select dt, symbol,null as ema3, id from cte1 where id < @prd 
union all
select dt, symbol, round(avg(close) over(partition by symbol order by dt
rows between 2 preceding and current row),2) as ema3, id from cte1 where id = @prd)


select dt, symbol, ema3 from ema
```

The code given calculates the ema's for the first three days for each symbol. However, I'm stuck on calculating the ema's for the succeeding days. I don't know how to reference the previous ema for each symbol in this formula: (close * alpha) + **prev. ema** * (1-alpha).

Comment: Before tackling this Question, please explain where the information will go.  That is, will you be storing the EMA for each symbol for each day somewhere?  Or is this a one-time fetching of EMAs to graph?  Etc.

Comment: @rick james, it will be stored in a new table with the ff. columns, date, symbol, ema3. Obviously, a new query will be formulated for each new insert which i'm also having a trouble.  I tried to calculate the ema via python pandas.ewm it was easy but the values doesn't match

Answer (score 1):

The beauty of EMA (over typical "moving average") is that you need to keep only one number, not the last N numbers.  (This is, of course, in addition to the 'constant' `alpha`.)

It's unfortunate that you did not start building the EMAs when you started collecting data.  As I see it, tomorrow's INSERT is almost trivial, given today's EMA and tomorrow's `close`.

Today's EMA could be stored permanently as a separate column in the big table with all the stock quotes.  Or the EMA for each stock could be stored in the `Stocks` table, but this would be transient; that is, it would change every day.

You have special-cased the first N-1 days; do this as an after thought.  That is, focus on how to compute tomorrow from today *first*.

**More**

After you have loaded all of today's closing prices into `closeTable`, run this on one query to load the corresponding `ema` values into the other table.

```
INSERT INTO emaTable  (symbol, date, ema)
    SELECT c.symbol, c.date,
           (c.close * 0.7 + e.ema * (1 - 0.7) AS new_ema
        FROM closeTable AS c
        JOIN emaTable AS e  ON e.symbol = c.symbol
                          AND e.date = c.date - INTERVAL 1 DAY
        WHERE date = CURDATE();
```

I am assuming alpha = 0.7; adjust as you see fit.

I suggest the datatype of `ema` be `FLOAT`; Decimal would incur a roundoff that might lead to some strange values.  When fetching `ema` for display, round it then.

(I would probably have `ema` in the main table.)

Assuming the stock market is closed on weekends and holidays, the "yesterday" code won't always work.  One way to get the value of "yesterday":  `SELECT MAX(date) FROM emaTable`